# Upgrade IdentityServer4 from 2.2 to 3.1 error

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I am updating IdentityServer4 from 2.2 to 3.1, I cannot run pass app.UseEndpoints. Here is the exception

Unable to load one or more of the requested types.\r\nCould not load type 'IdentityModel.Client.DiscoveryResponse' from assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f'

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        try
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                SeedData.EnsureSeedData(serviceScope, Configuration);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        //app.UseIdentityServer();
        //app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
        //app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        // app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
```

I did a search, found the following link.
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/issues/245
But, I still cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: You need to give us more information. Where is your exception thrown? What is the call stack? Where are you using `IdentityModel`? Try to start by reproducing your issue inside a new clean project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. Here is the link for solution.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3986